Firebase App Check Blocking Legitimate Traffic
on my client side I have set up App Check like so:
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

let db = getFirestore(app)
let auth = getAuth(app)
let storage = getStorage(app)
let functions = getFunctions(app)
let remoteConfig = getRemoteConfig(app)
let appCheck

const isEmulator = window.location.hostname === 'localhost'

if (isEmulator) {
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080)
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099')
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, 'localhost', 9199)
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001)
} else {
  appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_CHECK_TOKEN),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
  })
}

export { db, auth, storage, functions, appCheck, remoteConfig }

on my back end, an example onCall looks like the following:
const createWebSession = onCall(
  {
    minInstances: 5,
    enforceAppCheck: process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR !== 'true'
  },
  async (request) => {
    if (!request.app && !process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR) {
      log(`App Check: ${JSON.stringify(request.app)}`)
      throw new HttpsError(
        'unauthenticated',
        'The function must be called by an App Check verified app or from the emulator.'
      )
    }

    // function logic
  }
)

export default createWebSession

I am using recaptcha v3, and I've set up the allowed domains and registered my web app in firebase using the secret key provided by the recaptcha admin site.  The recaptcha admin console shows 14k requests and around 5.5% being marked as suspicious.  My fear is that legitimate traffic is getting blocked and I'm unsure how to validate that app check is working properly.  Is there anything I missed in setting up App Check or anything I can do to ensure valid requests are not being blocked.
